# The closed unit ball to generate a linear normed space.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a linear normed space and let B denote the closed unit ball of $X$. Then 
we can stretch the unit ball to get every vector in $X$: $$X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty nB.$$ 
Is this true? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Given $x\in X$, there is $n\in\Bbb N$ with $\|x\|\le n$. Then $x\in nB$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, in a normed space every neighbourhood of $0$ is absorbing, as this property is also called. For, if $x \in X$, take $n = 1 + \lceil\|x\|\rceil \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\|x\| < n$. Then $\|\frac{1}{n}\cdot x\| = \frac{1}{n}\|x\|  <1$ So $x = n \cdot (\frac{1}{n}\cdot x) \in nB$, as required.

IIRC, a locally convex topological vector space is normable exactly when this property holds for all (open) neighbourhoods of $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Because it is also a linear space is X=span(B)?

Comment: Sure, this then follows. @AnswerLee